# PHPMailer() Repeating E-mail Content

Tags: phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer() to send files to a specific e-mail address from a contact form in my website. However, I am having a problem with the e-mail contents that I receive.

For instance:
If I send e-mail using the form in my website, I receive the contents after a couple of minutes.
However, if I send another e-mail with different content (e.g Name, E-mail, Message, etc.), what arrives in my intended destination e-mail address is the content of my first e-mail.

**UPDATE**:

```
<?php

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$name       = $_REQUEST['name'];
$phone      = $_REQUEST['phone'];
$email      = $_REQUEST['email'];
$subject    = $_REQUEST['subject'];
$message    = $_REQUEST['message'];

############################ E-mail Credentials ############################
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput  = 'html';
$mail->Host         = "localhost";
$mail->Port         = 25;
$mail->SMTPAuth     = true; 
$mail->Username     = "#######";
$mail->Password     = "#######";
$mail->setFrom('#######', '#######');
$mail->addReplyTo('#######', '#######');
$mail->addAddress('#######', '#######');
############################################################################

$mail->Subject      = '[Online] '. $subject;
$mail->Body         = $message;
$mail->AltBody      = $message;

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

Comment: clear all the variables that hold the email parameters before reusing them

Comment: Please share your code ..

Comment: @prady00 I have placed the code.

Comment: Try adding unset($mail); on last line

Comment: It didn't work, Sir. I still have to send another e-mail before I can receive the last e-mail.